# Assembler Malloc dies on me

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, malloc, glibc

I am trying to allocate two chunks of memory and write to one of them (NASM, Linux 86_64 on Arch that I updated today, glibc):

```
        global  main
        extern  malloc

section .text
main:
        mov rdi, 5
        call malloc
        mov qword [array], rax
        mov qword [rax+24], 5 ; mov qword [rax+8], 5 or mov qword [rax+10000] doesn't die on me
        mov rdi, 5
        call malloc


section .bss
        array resq    1
```

When i do:

```
nasm -felf64 test.s; gcc test.o; ./a.out
```

I get:

```
test.out: malloc.c:2395: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.
Keskeytetty (luotiin core-tiedosto)
```

(The last line translates to English roughly as Interrupted (created a core-file), ie. core dumped)

Googling and searching SO tells me that I am probably writing into something malloc set up for its own internal use. Practical tests seem to corroborate this (the error only happens if I indeed try to write.).

However I couldn't find what I am supposed to do to prevent this. Could someone with more insight tell me what I should do?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but isn't your call to Malloc only reserving space for 5 bytes? And then you write 8 bytes (64-bit value)to [rax+24] which happens to start 24 bytes into a malloced region of 5 bytes. Maybe you intended to malloc a region of 5 quadwords (5*8)which would have been a size of 40 being passed to malloc?

Comment: Whoopsie... OK, thanks. Do you want to write it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Naw, I think there is probably a question elsewhere about malloc taking size as bytes. If you wish to answer your own question with my hint please be my guest.

Comment: If you don't *really* need to be able to free a block separately, you should use one larger `malloc`.  It's not very efficient to make many tiny allocations.  Also, your answer says "seems to take its size as bytes", like this was somehow mysterious.  The man page (`malloc(3)`) is clear about it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, as stated by Michael Petch, malloc seems to take its size as bytes. So this would work:

```
        global  main
        extern  malloc

section .text
main:
        mov rdi, 40 ; 5*8
        call malloc
        mov qword [array], rax
        mov qword [rax+24], 5 ; mov qword [rax+8], 5 or mov qword [rax+10000] doesn't die on me
        mov rdi, 5
        call malloc


section .bss
        array resq    1
```

Comment: [malloc is absolutely based on bytes](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/malloc.html).  it always has been.

Comment: I apollogize for not being aquinted with that. Personally I have only used it from C with malloc(n*sizeof(int))-type constructs.